# CSS: Very simple image gallery

Tags: css, html, image

I don't always do web development, but when I do CSS is the most frustrating thing I can imagine. I'm trying to create a simple class to hold an image together with description. I want to have two rows, each with three images. Very simple.

Here's my code for displaying images only, which works ok.

```
img {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 650px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 10px 0 5px 0;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;  
}

<h3>Screenshots</h3>

<p>
<a href="images/img1.png"><img src="images/img1.png" width="200" height="140"></a>
<a href="images/img2.png"><img src="images/img2.png" width="200" height="140"></a>
<a href="images/img3.png"><img src="images/img3.png" width="200" height="140"></a>
<a href="images/img4.png"><img src="images/img4.png" width="200" height="140"></a>
<a href="images/img5.png"><img src="images/img5.png" width="200" height="140"></a>
<a href="images/img6.png"><img src="images/img6.png" width="200" height="140"></a>
</p>


<h3>Installation</h3>
```

This shows images exactly as I want, three in each row and then there's a padding from < p > and then *Installation* section. To get description under images in the same div I changed img in css to div.img and htm code to:

```
<h3>Screenshots</h3>

<p>
<div class="img">
  <a target="_blank" href="images/img1.png"><img src="images/img1.png" width="200" height="140"></a>
</div>
<div class="img">
  <a target="_blank" href="images/img1.png"><img src="images/img1.png" width="200" height="140"></a>
</div>
<div class="img">
  <a target="_blank" href="images/img1.png"><img src="images/img1.png" width="200" height="140"></a>
</div>
<div class="img">
  <a target="_blank" href="images/img1.png"><img src="images/img1.png" width="200" height="140"></a>
</div>
<div class="img">
  <a target="_blank" href="images/img1.png"><img src="images/img1.png" width="200" height="140"></a>
</div>
<div class="img">
  <a target="_blank" href="images/img1.png"><img src="images/img1.png" width="200" height="140"></a>
</div>
</p>

<h3>Installation</h3>
```

One would have thought that the resulting webpage is going to be exactly the same as img in the first case and div.img in the second have the same attributes. It is not the case though. With this code I get each div stretched to the full width of the column and images are one under the other at the left side of the div.

I have also tried this code: http://www.w3schools.com/CSS/css_image_gallery.asp, but in this case I get *Installation* and all the text that follows go onto the images, ignoring < p > tag which has bottom margin.

Comment: Please make jsfiddle and I will make everything work for you :)

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/XyURM.jpg

Comment: @Truth that's exactly what came to my mind when I read the first sentence!

Comment: @skmasq Here you go, that almost works, but as you can see, "Installation" text goes onto the images and < p > margin seems to not apply: http://jsfiddle.net/Znk9y/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To keep it simple: replace your divs with `<span>` elements, or set `display: inline` on your CSS for the divs. This will make them behave as you expected (as *inline*, not *block* elements).

Also:

- You don't need the `margin: 0 auto`. It won't center inline elements as it does with block elements
- You added `position: relative`, but don't seem to need it, either. Unless you intend to apply `absolute` position to something inside the div at a later point.

Here is a jsfiddle without these two properties, and adding `display: inline` to the divs: http://jsfiddle.net/3BwKY/.

Comment: This results, as also seen on jsfiddle, in borders being displayed under the images.

Comment: You can use `display: inline-block` on the divs then: http://jsfiddle.net/3BwKY/2/